# getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: mysql

I am using docker to run nginx, mariadb and php (8.1) on a Mac with M1.
I installed Laravel on the host, using composer and set up my database credentials in the .env file.

When I ran `php artisan migrate` on the host I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = api and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I already searched and found, that this could be related to the `DB_HOST` setting.
Mine is: `mysql`, what is the `container_name`. I tried `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` or `localhost` as well with the same result.

Within mysql I get:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = "api" and table_name = "migrations" and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
Empty set (0,03 sec)
```

This is my manifest:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "433:443"
        environment:
            - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
        command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
    php:
        container_name: php
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm:${PHP_VERSION}
        platform: linux/x86_64
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        platform: linux/x86_64
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:${MYSQL_VERSION}
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname 'mysql' only works if you run it in a docker-compose or when the container is linked other ways or if you specify that in your /etc/hosts file. I guess the issue is that you need to run that artisan command inside that php container (instead of running it from the host itself) with docker exec something like this:

```
docker exec -it <php-containers-name> php artisan migrate
```

The other way is to expose the db containers port to the host so you can access it with 0.0.0.0:3306.

Using the docker-compose instead of pure docker to relay to the right containers then. What is the output of this command?

```
docker-compose exec -w="/var/www/html" php php artisan migrate
```

(It runs a 'php artisan migrate' inside the php container using /var/www/html as a working directory)

Comment: Hi ty, but this does not help, unfortunately. I added my docker-compose.yml

Comment: The output is: `Could not open input file: artisan`

Comment: Is the ./web folder considered as your laravel project root? Where is the artisan file in your host system?

Comment: Laravel is installed into ./web/api/. I don't know how to find the artisan file, but in my host (not using my docker setup, but using MAMP for example) I have no issues with  php artisan commands

Comment: Then replace the '/var/www/html' with '/var/www/html/api'

Comment: I want to switch from MAMP to Docker. I don't want to use php inside docker to run commands. php is installed on my host as well. I want to interact with Laravel through the host. Docker is just holding the database and handling the virtual hosts, but I am exposing the port of mysql and want to use it from the host

Comment: Now I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.3' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = api and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: Can you show me the 'docker ps' output? Tried the same on my M1 and went fine with latest laravel, 8.1 php and latest mariadb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244465/discussion-between-peterpan-and-tacsiazuma).